# Cannot convert lambda expression to type string because it is not a delegate type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda

I am trying to create a link-button with the following structure/code:

```
<%:school => string.Format("<a class='add' href='{0}' title='Add {1} to {4}'><img class='pic2' alt='{2}' src='{3}'/></a>",
                                          Url.Action("AddSchoolToParty", "PartySchool",
                                          new { partyId = Model.PartyId, schoolId = school.SchoolId }),
                                          School.EntityName, string.Empty,
                                          Url.Content("~/Content/images/addImage.png"),
                                          School.EntityName)%>
```

The error i am getting is:

**CS1660: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type**

Also is this the proper format for creating the link with the information that i have for it?

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Kids.MVC.Models.ViewModels.SchoolFormViewModel>" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="Kids.Resources" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Kids.Resources.Entities" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="MvcContrib.Pagination" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="MvcContrib.UI.Grid" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="MvcContrib.UI.Pager" %>
<%: Html.ValidationSummary(true, Message.ValidationErrorSummary, new{@class= "error"}) %>
<%=Html.DatePickerEnable() %>
```

**This is a format that i used in a different page and this this the button link that i want to rewrite in just  tag without the column and string.format - i want to know the proper way of rewriting this link.**

```
column.For(
                        school =>
                        string.Format("<a class='add' href='{0}' title='Add {1} to {4}'><img class='pic2' alt='{2}' src='{3}'/></a>",
                                      Url.Action("AddSchoolToParty", "PartySchool",
                                      new { partyId = Model.PartyId, schoolId = school.SchoolId }),
                                      School.EntityName, string.Empty,
                                      Url.Content("~/Content/images/addImage.png"),
                                      School.EntityName)).Encode(false).Sortable(false);
```

Comment: did you add using System.Linq; into the html code?

Comment: Yes why are you using a lambda

Comment: @JoshuaEnfield when i removed it - it shows `school` in `schooldId = school.SchoolId` in red and cannot resolve symbol.

Comment: We need more. Where is "school" coming from or what is it? Is it part of your model?  Do you mean to type **S** chool as to refer to a possible static class like the lines below it? (note the capital S)

Comment: Alternatively is `SchoolId` part of a class with "static" on it? Is it part of SchoolFormViewModel? Based on your usage of the lambda you might mean to type `Model.SchoolId` instead of `school.SchoolId.` You can't use a lambda here.

Comment: @JoshuaEnfield - i added the top of my controler page. What i am trying to do is: I have this button that i used in a different page and it was in a table in a column as shown above in last snippet of code - and now i am trying to place the same link information in a simple <a> tab as a button/link

Comment: @JoshuaEnfield I tried `<a class="glossyBtn" href='<%:Url.Action("AddSchoolToPartyPage", "PartySchool", new{partyId = Model.PartyId, schoolId = Model.SchoolId })%>'>Add School</a>` but the error i get is: System.ArgumentException: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'schoolId' of non-nullable type 'System.Guid' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult AddSchoolToPartyPage(System.Guid, System.Guid)' in 'Kids.MVC.Controllers.PartySchoolController'.

Comment: What is this `column` variable out there? This is not valid syntax. Are you using some third party control? If so you should state clearly which one.

Comment: With your edits the original usage of the lambda looks more correct, but as Darin mentions why are you using column.For? What do you expect that to do?

Comment: @JoshuaEnfield I stated above the column use. which was used in a different page i just want to rewrite what is in that string.format into a proper <a> tag to use as a link.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
<a class="add" href="<%: Url.Action("AddSchoolToParty", "PartySchool", new { partyId = Model.PartyId, schoolId = Model.SchoolId }) %>" title="<%: string.Format("Add {0} to {0}", School.EntityName) %>">
    <img class="pic2" alt="" src="<%: Url.Content("~/Content/images/addImage.png") %>" />
</a>
```

But to avoid this ugly tag soup I would recommend you writing a custom HTML helper which will make this syntax much more clear.

Comment: Thanks for your help i really appreciate it - I tried your suggested code and it looks great but now when i use it on my page i get this error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "School_PartySchool_FK1". The conflict occurred in database "Kids", table "dbo.School", column 'SchoolId'.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: I really don't see how this code snippet has anything to do with this exception. I suppose that this is completely unrelated.